# Where is the "additional drivers" dialog?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

where is the "additional drivers" dialog in Ubuntu 12.10?

I can't find it in the dashboard.